# finding max in python

Tags: python

```py
def loop():
   maxi = height[0]  
   for index in range [1,3]:        
      if height[index] > maxi:            
         maxi = [index]  
         print(maxi)

#main program

name=["jane_wilson","andrew_carter","mark_roland","anabelle_walker"]
number=["0133412345","0133454321","0133413579","0133497531"]
height=[2.15,1.79,2.32,1.41]
```

so i have this code and I need to find max then display all the info on the person with the highest height but it exists In parallel arrays and i don't know what to do and I'm stuck as the code is just not working

Answer (score 1):

You can sort zipped values by height and take the first value:

```
all_info = list(zip(name, number, height))
all_info_sorted = sorted(all_info, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(all_info_sorted[-1])
```

Comment: Besides the fact that you don't give out the person with the maximum height but the person with the minimum number value this is OK. But you don't even need to sort because `max` has a `key` parameter too. So it all boils down to: `print(max(zip(name, number, height), key=lambda x: x[2]))`

Comment: @Matthias, thank you for the pointing to incorrect index, I fixed it.
And I also love your solution very much, I vote for it!

Answer (score 1):

You just, want the index of the maximum entry of the list "height". That should be:

```
idx = height.index(max(height))
```

and then you can print it:

```
print(f"{name[idx]} has a height of {height[idx]}, and a phone number: {number[idx]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the max function here.

```
max_h = max(height)
index = height.index(max_h)
max_name = name[index]
max_number = number[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do first is to find the subsript of the highest height. That's what your function 'loop' trying to do. But there are some problems.
You need to write like that:

```
def loop():
   maxi = height[0]  
   for index in range [1,3]:        
      if height[index] > maxi:            
         maxi = [index]
```

After doing that, you will find the subsript of the highest height. And then, you can print them all.

```
print(number[maxi])
print(name[maxi])
```